# How to move VM to a new Virtual Network in Azure Portal

Tags: azure

Can someone let me know how to move a VM from one Virtual Network to another. In the image, I would like to move the VM webtestnic-backend-.... from Virtual network 'webtestvnet-arrmb7u3eu35o to my VirtualNetork.

[azure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXQag.png)

Can you let me know how to do that?

Cheers

Carlton

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moving VMs between different VNET is not supported. To move the VM to another VNET, the only solution for now is re-create the VM with the same vhd file.

To redeploy the VM with same vhd file, please try this [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-from-specialized-vhd).

BTW, we are able to move the VMs between the subnets in the same VNET. It contains 3 steps:

1. Get the VM (NIC) configuration
2. Edit the VM (NIC) configuration
3. Update the edited configuration

Here is a good step-by-step guide:

[How to change Subnet and Virtual Network for Azure Virtual Machines (ASM & ARM)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/igorpag/2016/03/13/how-to-change-subnet-and-virtual-network-for-azure-virtual-machines-asm-arm/)

Comment: I guess it is now supported. See answer by @Mucker

Answer (score 1):

You can't move a VM to another Virtual Network without redeploying.

To redeploy a VM, I like [this](http://www.codeisahighway.com/how-to-use-arm-explorer-to-capture-your-own-custom-virtual-machine-image-under-azure-resource-manager/) method, but [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-capture-image/)'s Microsoft guide using Powershell. Just make sure to change the associated network interface for one within desired VNet.

Comment: Hi Bruno, thanks for responding. Looking at your powershell scripts, it doesn't appear to assigning the interface to a virtual network. However, it does assign the interface to a resource group. Don't I need to assign the interface to both the Resource group as well as  the virtual network?

Comment: I removed the cmdlets because I made a double check and realized you really can't move the VM to another Virtual Network without redeploy. You can change a NIC that is using a different configuration, but it still need to be in the same VNet. I used pipe in those cmdlets to avoid retyping some of the parameters like vm name.

Answer (score 1):

Although an old post now I'd like to list another solution I found recently when trying to figure out the same thing. It is possible to do this and automate the entire process using PowerShell. I found this excellent blog post which shows how to do it. Hope it helps!

https://think-like-a-computer.com/2020/02/06/azure-move-vm-to-another-vnet-powershell/

Comment: The link is dead. Thanks to the one who captured the web. This is the link to wayback machine https://web.archive.org/web/20200207051825/https://think-like-a-computer.com/2020/02/06/azure-move-vm-to-another-vnet-powershell/

Comment: I ran this script and my VM disappeared :(